# Python simple for loop issue

Tags: python

Currently learning python. Normally a C++ guy.

```
if wallpaper == "Y":
    charge = (70)
    print ("You would be charged £70")
    wallpaperList.append(charge)

elif wallpaper == "N" :
    charge = (0)

else:
    wallPaper ()

surfaceArea
    totalPapers = 0
    for item in range (len(wallpaperList)):
        totalPapers += wallpaperList[item]
```

I am trying do a for loop for the if statement.

In c++ this will just be a simple

```
for (I=0; i<pRooms; i++){
}
```

I am trying to add the above code in a for loop but I seem to fail.

Thanks

Comment: Show the code that's failing, please.

Comment: Not sure over what you're looping... if it's `pRooms`, you do `for i in xrange(pRooms):`

Comment: Please correct your indentation, also, currently there are mistakes, and in Python, indentation matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python loops iterate over everything in the iterable:

```
for item in wallpaperList:
        totalPapers += item
```

In modern C++, this is analogous to:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> wallpaperList;

// ...

for(auto item: wallpaperList) {
    totalPapers += item
}
```

You could also just use the `sum` function:

```
cost = sum(wallpaperList)
```

If the charge is `70` every time, why not just do multiplication?

```
while wallPaper == 'Y':
    # ...

    # Another satisfied customer!
    i += 1

cost = i * 70
```

Answer (score 2):

For the exact equivalent of your `for` loop, use `range`:

```
for (i=0; i<pRooms; i++){   # C, C++
}

for i in range(pRooms):     # Python
    ...
```

Both loops iterate over the values `0` to `pRooms-1`. But python gives you other options. You can iterate over the elements of the list without using an index:

```
for room in listOfRooms:
    if room.wallpaper == "Y":
        ...
```

*List comprehensions* are also nice. If you don't care about the `print` calls in your code, you could compute the cost in one line with something like this:

```
totalPapers = sum(70 for room in listOfRooms if room.wallpaper == "Y")
```